# Why is this simple function using unsigned products not working?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a homework assignment using recursion and my `productfz`  function will refuse to cooperate with me.  Visual Studio told me that I needed parenthesis around the 'first' variable when I call it in main.  I only added the 'unsigned' before each variable in my main argument because it got rid of the error message.  However, the function will not even execute.  I won't get the "tester" message in my run code.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 unsigned productfz();

 unsigned productfz(unsigned a, unsigned b)
 {
//nothing for now
    cout << "this is a tester" << endl;
return a;
 }

int main()
{

unsigned int first = 7;
unsigned b = 4;
unsigned productfz(unsigned first, unsigned b);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `main()` you are not calling productfz correctly the line:

```
  unsigned productfz(unsigned first, unsigned b);
```

is a function decleration not a function call.

If you want to call the function simply write:

```
 productfz(first,b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually calling your function, you're just declaring a prototype within `main` - change:

```
unsigned productfz(unsigned first, unsigned b);
```

to:

```
productfz(first, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify a variable's datatype when you pass it to a function. You also don't need to specify the method's return datatype when you call it.

This code should work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
unsigned productfz();

unsigned productfz(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
  //nothing for now
  cout << "this is a tester" << endl;
  return a;
}

int main()
{
  unsigned int first = 7;
  unsigned b = 4;
  productfz(first, b);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `unsigned` by itself means `unsigned int`

Comment: @odedsh Can you provide a reference for that? I've never seen `unsigned` by itself before.

Comment: In many cases `int` is implicit, e.g. `short` == `short int`, `unsigned` == `unsigned int`, etc. Try it with your favourite compiler.

Comment: Thanks to you both, I learned something new today. I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make following changes (also, formatted/aligned code is easier to understand and debug):

```
unsigned productfz(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    //nothing for now
    int a; // you are returning this variable but you have not defined/used it
    cout << "this is a tester" << endl;
    return a; 
}

int main()
{

    unsigned int first = 7;
    unsigned b = 4;
    productfz(first, b); //just write the variable names

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Originally posted code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 unsigned productfz();

 unsigned productfz(unsigned a, unsigned b)
 {
//nothing for now
    cout << "this is a tester" << endl;
return a;
 }

int main()
{

unsigned int first = 7;
unsigned b = 4;
unsigned productfz(unsigned first, unsigned b);

return 0;
}
```

Fixed & cleaned code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int productfz( int const a, int const b)
{
    //nothing for now
    cout << "this is a tester" << endl;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    productfz( 7, 4 );
}
```

where

- The forward declaration of `productfz` has been removed.
  Forward declarations
  just mean that two places have to be updated instead of one when a change is
  made, and they can introduce subtle errors when forward declaration and
  implementation get out fo synch.
- The type `unsigned` has been replaced with `int`.
  C++ guarantees modular arithmetic for unsigned types, *and* provides
  implicit conversions up from signed types to corresponding unsigned, when
  the two kinds are mixed in an expression. This means that if unsigned types
  are used **for numbers**, then you risk inadvertent use of modular
  arithmetic. For example, `string("haha").length() < -5` is always `true`,
  due to an ill-fated decision long ago (when it made sense) to have sizes
  represented with an unsigned integer type.
- The formal arguments have been `const`ified.
  Most everybody agree that it's a good idea to liberally sprinkle `const`
  everywhere that it's practical to do so, because that constrains the
  possible data interaction pathways and make the code easier to reason
  about and understand. However, few put `const` on ordinary value arguments.
  I do, because the same rationale applies to them as for e.g. local variables.
- The variables used as argument names, in `main`, have been removed.
  For a simple function with few arguments it doesn't really clarify
  anything to name the actual arguments. On the contrary, the added
  verbosity might have the opposite effect, of obscuring. Still, as a
  general rule it's a good idea to name just about everything in sight,
  so when in doubt, do name things.
- The redeclaration of the function in `main`, has been replaced with a **call**.
  A function `f` is called like `f( argument1, argument2, ... )`.
- The `return` statement in `main` has been removged.
  `main` is a very special function, with a default return value (namely 0).

Personally I would prefer to also use C++ `auto` syntax for the function declarations, because that makes it easier to scan the code and is *one* universal function declaration
syntax. However, that's still not very common practice, so I didn't do that here.